# Eigen: Concatenating matrices and vectors

Tags: matrix, eigen

Using the Eigen C++ library, I have a Matrix3f `A`, a Vector4f `b`, and a Vector4f `c`. I want to create a Matrix4f `M` out of these. I want the top 3-by-3 corner of `M` to be `A`, I want to final column of `M` to be `b`, and I want the bottom row of `M` to be `c`.

I know how to do this by simply creating a Matrix4f and assigning each element individually. But is there a more elegant solution that Eigen supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this count as elegant enough?

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Matrix4f m = Matrix4f::Random();
    Matrix3f A = Matrix3f::Constant(0.1);
    Vector4f b = Vector4f::Constant(0.2), c = Vector4f::Constant(0.3);
    cout << m << endl << endl;
    cout << A << endl << endl;
    cout << b << endl << endl;
    cout << c << endl << endl;

    m.block(0, 0, 3, 3) = A;
    m.col(3) = b;
    m.row(3) = c;

    cout << m << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that your question is kinda ambiguous, as the (3,3) position will be determined by the order of assignment between `b` and `c`.

Comment: What if `b` is actually a Vector3f? Can you still assign the first three elements of the last column to `b` using `m.col(3) = b`, or does `b` have to be a Vector4f?

Comment: @Karnivaurus No, they have to be the same size. You can specify `m.block(0,3,3,1) = b;` instead.